# openpyxl - specify column to read from

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I have searched on how to use openpyxl to read values from a column but instead of specifying the column by a value like A, B, C, I am trying to specify what column to read from based on a string and read the rows below the specified string while essentially ignoring the ones above.

I have a few different spreadsheets that follow a similar format but not exactly the same meaning they contain the same information but not in the same format.

[The spreadsheets all contain columns with first and last name, a unique ID for the contractors account, as well as some other confidential info. In this case I am trying to read the rows under the column named "ID" instead of specifying the column as A and the rows as 13-47.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AJ2X5.png)

Is there a way to do this? I haven't found anything on reading values without specifying columns by their letter or rows by their number.

Answer (score 1):

First create a column title to column letter map using a dictionary.
Then use the column letter to iterate for values. I did handle such scenario like the following:

```
# Method to get a map of column index and column name
# Argument to this method is: - Row number of header row
def ref_col_idx_name_map(self, _header_row_num):
    # Create an empty dictionary
    col_idx_name_map = dict()
    # Iterate over the values of the header row
    # starting with index value of 0
    for _col_idx, _col_cells in enumerate(
            self.my_base_active_ws.iter_cols(min_row=_header_row_num, max_row=_header_row_num, values_only=True),
            start=1):
        col_idx_name_map[_col_idx] = _col_cells[0]
    # Return type is dictionary
    return col_idx_name_map
##################
from openpyxl.utils import column_index_from_string
# Method to get column values for a given column name
# Arguments to this method are:- Row number for header row & column name
def get_specific_col_val_by_col_name_in_active_ws(self, _header_row_num, _col_name):
    # Check if provided column name exists in the worksheet
    if _col_name in self.ref_col_idx_name_map(_header_row_num).values():
        # Fetch the values from the column provided
        # Skip the header row
        # Fetch the column index from column name using 'ref_col_name_letter_map' method
        return [_col_value[0] for _col_value in self.my_base_active_ws.iter_rows(min_row=_header_row_num + 1,
                                                                                 min_col=column_index_from_string(
                                                                                     self.ref_col_name_letter_map(
                                                                                         _header_row_num)[
                                                                                         _col_name]),
                                                                                 max_col=column_index_from_string(
                                                                                     self.ref_col_name_letter_map(
                                                                                         _header_row_num)[
                                                                                         _col_name]),
                                                                                 values_only=True)]
```